# How can I write the t-statistic in cases where I have three populations and linear relationship between the three?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, inference

I sample height measurements from people from three populations, which I call P1, P2, and P3.

My null hypothesis that the average height in group P1 equals 2/3 times the group P2 average plus 1/3 times the group C average. The alternative I have is that the average height in group P1 IS NOT EQUAL to 2/3 times the group P2 average plus 1/3 times the group C average. In this type of problem, how can I write out the t-statistic and the null distribution? My first through is the three way ANOVA, but am not sure if writing it out in a t-statistic is possible. Thanks!

Comment: You might do some browsing on the topic of testing "contrasts" in ANOVA.  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: Why a three way ANOVA?

Comment: If it's a homework problem, please add a `self-study` tag.